# Use of SVG in precacheImage in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, flutter-provider

My app uses many images so to reduce the size of app I used SVG instead of PNG. Now I am unable to use SVG as `precacheImage`. I have used `SvgPicture` instead of `AssetImage` but still not working.

```
    static void precacheMeasures(BuildContext context) async {
for (int i = 0; i < MeasureCategoriesEnum.values.length; ++i) {
  final MeasureCategoriesEnum category = MeasureCategoriesEnum.values[i];
  final List<MeasuresEnum> measures = categories[category]!;
  for (MeasuresEnum measure in measures) {
    final String caption = TypeHelpers.getEnumCaption(measure);
    final MeasureCategoriesEnum? category =
        categories.keys.firstWhereOrNull((MeasureCategoriesEnum k) => categories[k]!.contains(measure));
    precacheImage(AssetImage('Resources/Images/Measures/${TypeHelpers.getEnumCaption(category)}/$caption.svg'), context);
  }
}
```

Any solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `SvgPicture.asset('assetname.svg')`. It's available through the `flutter_svg` package on Pub: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg.

It should behave just as any other asset image would.